# sql where clause where date like MM:SS is defined only

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, where-clause

I want to only query where `timestamp` field MM:SS = `00:00` I do not care of `MM/DD/YYYY HH` I only want to query where MM:SS = `00:00`

Sample Query

`select ID, Timestamp from TableT where timestamp like`??? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not real familiar with oracle, but the following may work for you:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Timestamp 
FROM TableT AS t
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t.timestamp) = 0
  AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM t.timestamp) = 0
```

Comment: I do not care about hour, so I can just change change hour to `SECOND`?

Comment: *@user206168*, yeah I just modified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Just a side note, TIMESTAMP is a [**reserved word**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) in Oracle.  Just FYI, it is good practice not to use reserved words as field names in tables.

Comment: Hi, EXTRACT give me this error `ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source.` I was able to use `where to_char(sysdate,'ss') = 0` if you add this as second answer I will mark down as best answer. Thanks for help again.

Answer (score 0):

From an Oracle SQL perspective (and taking into consideration Oracle date format models,http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210 ) your question is not clear.

MI is for minutes

MM is for months (01-12)

SS is for seconds.

```
select ID, 
    Timestamp_col 
from TableT 
where 
    to_char(Timestamp_col,'MI:SS') = '00:00';
```